# Spring REST controller, deserialising inside of transaction

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, transactions

I have a following problem that I'm struggling to solve. I've got a JPA entity that contains lazy-loaded Set of `@OneToMany` entities (code below).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SKILL")
public class Skill {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SKILL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Skill parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Set<Skill> children;

    public Skill() {

    }

    // getters-setters ommitted
}
```

Here's a code from Spring REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/skill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Skill>> listAllSkills() {
    Iterable<Skill> skills = skillService.getAllSkills();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Lists.newArrayList(skills), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Whenever I try to return the entity from this controller, it throws

```
JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of 
role: com.juriy.arcadia.domain.Skill.children, could not initialize 
proxy - no Session
```

As far as I understood, what happens is Jackson is trying lazy-load parts of the entity outside of transaction bounds, that's why Session is not found. If I add a dirty hack and call the parts that are supposed to be lazy-loaded manually within the transaction, it works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/skill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Skill>> listAllSkills() {

    Iterable<Skill> skills = skillService.getAllSkills();

    // Hack here: load required items inside of session bounds
    for (Skill s : skills) {
        System.out.println("Fetched skills: "+ s.getChildren().size());
        System.out.println("Fetched parent: "+ s.getParent());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Lists.newArrayList(skills), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Question:** What is a supposed way to organise deserialisation in a case of lazy-loading and transactions. Is there a way to put deserialisation inside of transaction bounds?

**related question:** I heard that it isn't a good practice to make controller layer `@Transactional`. What's the best way to design transaction in this case?

**UPDATE:** adding `EAGER` loading of entities is not an option in my case (there's a large tree of entities and `EAGER` loading will load the whole tree which will totally kill the performance).

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is calling the getter on parent outside of the JPA transaction so the lazy loaded entity is not available anymore.

Either change to Fetch.EAGER or add an assembler layer (i.e. a layer which converts the entity to a POJO).

Or add a @Transaction annotation to the

```
@Transaction
@RequestMapping(value = "/skill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Skill>> listAllSkills() {
    Iterable<Skill> skills = skillService.getAllSkills();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Lists.newArrayList(skills), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This assume you have set up the transaction manager correctly.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, for technical reason I can't have EAGER fetching (there's a large graph of entities connected with parent-child relationships and this will cause a snowball loading of the whole DB). Putting the @Transactional on the method or on the class level did not help, since methods return *before* the deserialisation start.

Comment: I take you point about @Transaction.  Maybe you should be adding Hateos links in your Json so the child entities for they are truly lazyily loaded.  Other option is to use hibernate 2nd level cache that will lighten the database load.

Comment: Or best of all I think, looking at the method, add a @Cache annotation to the method, and make the Fetchtype.EAGER. see https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/

Comment: Thanks for hints, HATEOS might actually help. Also I was thinking if I could return a serialised representation of an entity (for example JSON in String) from Controller. If I do serialisation by hand, then it will stay inside of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return list of all Skills you have to use FetchType.EAGER. Lazy loading would not load data without accesing it directly. That's why you have that error.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option, since there's a graph of dependent entities and this approach will load way too much. I'm trying to extend the bounds of transaction to the point where deserialisation is happening.